# Connect a wire to a circuit board

Tags: pcb

I'm really new in designing PCB(it's my first one) and i'm using Eagle Cad do it, however i have no idea on how to connect an outside wire to the PCB(either in the schematic or in a real circuit board). In this case the wire only needs to be connected to GND don't know if its easier or not.

thanks

Comment: Just add a pin header or other connector to your schematic and connect to whatever nets you want to expose.

Comment: For more options, try googling "wire to board connectors"

Answer (score 1):

If it's earth you want, you may be able to use a mounting hole. Show the mounting hole(s) on the schematic like any other component with a footprint and connect them where they should go (if anywhere).

If it's a wire to be soldered into a hole into the board, again, make a component footprint (preferably with strain relief).

You can also crimp a terminal onto the wire and solder the terminal into the board, use a board-to-wire connector pair (the 0.156" pitch series is good for high currents, whereas 2.54/2.50/2.0 mm pitch is good for finer individual wires. Or a screw terminal strip if connections are to be made in the field (there are even versions that use springs suitable for some applications that require no tools). Another possibility is to use Faston (tm) spades soldered into the board and female spade connectors crimped to the ends of the wires. The latter is very popular in appliance and commercial electronics that has to handle mains voltage at relatively high current.

[image: Link from here:http://www.dadaelectronics.eu/Images/ProductImages/PCB/Faston%20M%205.jpg]

Again, find or make a component symbol and a footprint that suits the part you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

For physically connecting wires to boards, I am a big fan of screw terminal blocks like these....

[image]

You can get them quickly, cheaply, and easily on Amazon, Digikey, and everywhere else.

You can find the footprints in Eagle `con-` libraries based on the number of terminals and the spacing you end up using .

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use Pins, to just solder the wire directly onto the board, a lot of the time I use screw connectors like the answer above, i recommend Upverter, eagle cad is a load utter crap. Upverter is free, easy to use and has a web app, but thats just my view.

Edited my question: For grounding your board you usually set a point where when the board is put into what ever your going to be putting it into it touches a metal part somewhere, that will ground it, what is it your designing?

Comment: I'm designing a simple board with only  3 components, only to understand a bit more about this subject, im an electrical engineering student but all my lectures only teach the theoretical part of electronics. The pins seems to work fine thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.